# How to Force HTTPS on a WordPress and remove HTTPS from permalinks

Tags: permalinks, ssl

I have recently secured SSL certificates for my website and I would like to force HTTPS for all visitors.

And i want to remove HTTPS From permalinks

Like this

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.mysite.com/archive/ID/" />
```

anyone suggest me plz

Answer (score 1):

This plugin should handle what you're requesting.
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/

Comment: That I know, but I'd without a plugin

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Which permalinks are you trying to change and in what context?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it via the wp-config with

```
define('WP_HOME','https://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com');
```

or you can do it via the .htaccess with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```